# Git how to merge repository into specific directory?

Tags: git

I worked on a new version (rewrote it in go) of my project in a seperate repository. Now that I have basically implemented all functionality in the rewrite, I would like to add it to the main repository into a directory called `backend` or something.

I would prefer keeping the commits I did in the seperate repository, otherwise I would just copy all the source files.

I have already tried adding the new repository as a remote and merging, but it puts the source files in the repository root, not in a seperate directory.

The tree of the rewrite repository looks something like this:

```
.
├── db
│   ├── file1.go
│   ├── file2.go
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── docs.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── logging
│   └── logging.go
├── main.go
├── README.md
├── routes
│   ├── route1.go
│   ├── route2.go
```

The tree of the original repository looks something like this:

```
.
├── backend
├── backend-old
└── frontend
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use of `git submodules`. See: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: You could use something like [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to make a clone of your rewrite repository with everything renamed (probably using `--to-subdirectory-filer backend`).